# Fill a column with repetitive data

Tags: sql, oracle, iteration

I have two columns, A and B:
A have some Primary Key ID:

```
     A           B
_ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _
DCS000111      Null
DCS000112      Null
DCS000113      Null
DCS000115      Null
DCS000119      Null
```

I would like to have a script, that can iterate through the table and fill the `null` value with

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Like this:

```
 A           B
_ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _
DCS000111      1
DCS000112      2
DCS000113      3
DCS000115      1
DCS000119      2
```

Thanks in Advance.

I know the script to replace the values from Column B with a single value, but, not sure with this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the value in a `select` using:

```
select a, mod(row_number() over (order by a) - 1, 3) + 1 as b
from t;
```

This is a pain to put into an update in Oracle.  You can use `merge`:

```
merge into t using
      (select a, mod(row_number() over (order by a) - 1, 3) + 1 as b
       from t
      ) tt
      on t.a = tt.a
    when matched then update set t.b = tt.b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `NTILE` function.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm

Simply apply according to your partition and ordering requirements and form an `UPDATE` statement.

```
update MyTable
set B=t from  
( 
select 
NTILE(3) over (order by A) as t from MyTable
) as z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of the 1,2,3 (and given any degree of change in your table's records why would you?) it's simply a matter of:

```
update your_table
set b = mod(rownum,3)+1
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, unfortunately, I have to take the order into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I took a copy of the original table, and created a new table, filling/re-iterating that required column with the `1, 2, 3` (Value1, Value2, Value3) information; then merged both the tables using `MOD`, using the below query.

INSERT INTO  SELECT ColA, DECODE ( MOD(rownum , 3) , 0 , 'Value1' , 1 , 'Value2' , 2,  'Value3' ) AS ColB FROM ;